# Map with percentages when conditions are met

Tags: maps, geospatial, geo, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

At the moment we are testing Tableau in a Proof of Concept. As a part it, I'm trying to create a map in Tableau that shows percentages on neighborhood level. To do so, i use the following data:

- neigborhood shapefile

Data file containing:

- energy labels for homes
- building year
- building worth

So for example the enduser can select the enery labels of interest, let's say A,B and C. Also, he/she is looking for houses worth > € 400.000, that were build after 1950.
The map should show a percentage of every neighborhood, that represents the houses that met the criteria diveded by the total number of houses in that neighborhood. I want the map percentages to be able to change dynamically.

Who can inform we what steps to take?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a proper shapefile and data, then this needs a bit of effort only. unfortunately you've not share your work in Tableau Public. You may refer here for more detail, also connect with me using "Hire Me" : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar/vizzes